# Getting error while installing Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, installation

I am trying to install spring boot's latest version 4.19 and getting the below error. Earlier I had 4.18. I deleted the older version. I have deleted all the files from the computer but still getting errors. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrad5.png)
Please help to resolve this error.

Comment: Looks like your question is related to STS and not spring boot.